# Setup default Ruby variables in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I use mac and rubymine *7.1.2* and I want to setup default environment variables? Is it possible to setup them up per run configuration so every test, rails generator, rails console has access to them.

Is there something like `.env` file or something else, so it's possible just set them once?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these? You can always set/access environment variables (these are system-wide). Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to setup db connection string, aws parameters, etc in my environment variables and I don't want to add those to development.rb file, because I use docker to run db, other dev just runs it from localhost, and some other differences as well. I know I can export those variables in ~/.bash_profile, however I want to have those variables exported per project.

Comment: Would setting them in some other configuration file work? Say `project_config.rb`. You could use this file for all of those default variables and just instantiate the config class to get to the variables.

Comment: @jkeuhlen this would only add extra complexity to ruby code. Also most of the variables are not common between developers. Something like ```.env``` file would totally work if rails or rubymine could read & export it

Comment: I found some information from Jetbrains (who produces RubyMine) that tells you just how to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetbrains actually has [a page](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1160) to help you do just this:

> Mac OS X applies .bash_profile and .profile only for Terminal.app environment and  Apple's technical documentation suggests using ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist for other applications. So, by default  PATH value will differ for RubyMine and the console.
>
> ```
> MacOS 10.6 or later
> ```
>
> We recommend to manage your environment variables using [free
>   Enviroment Variables](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCEnvironment/) preference pane instead of environment.plist
>   manual editing.
>
> ```
> MacOS < 10.6
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, the "environment.plist" approach doesn't always work on
>   MacOS < 10.6, e.g if you start RubyMine from Spotlight the environment
>   is not applied.
>
> Thus real solution is to set your environment variables in
>   /etc/launchd.conf (thanks to David Goudreau for this tip). For
>   detailed description please read Mac OS X Global Environment Variables
>   article.
>
> So you should:
>
> 1. Open /etc/launchd.conf file (e.g. $sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf)
> 2. Then set correct PATH env variable
>
>    ```
>    setenv PATH /Users/romeo/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/libexec/git-core:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>    ```
> 3. Set other env variables for RubyMine if necessary
> 4. Save changes
> 5. Reboot
>
> P.S: If you always launch RubyMine using Dock or QuickSilver and do
>   not use Spotlight you can install Enviroment Variables preference pane
>   and use it instead of the manual environment.plist editing.
>
> NB: Please don't miss "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   in the end of PATH value, because PATH=...:$PATH doesn't work here.

Comment: Do you also feel some bad smell here? Simple activity to setup env variables becomes pain in the ass.

Comment: @VladMiller It may be, but that's because you are setting them specifically for RubyMine rather than system wide. If this solves your problem, don't forget to accept! :)